# How to fix Error in Maven build for new spring boot application intialized from start.spring.io

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to set up a spring-boot project initialized using start.spring.io

This Error is showing up in initial build Pom.xml

[Error Screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/pQVCh7v/Screenshot-1.png)

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.2 from https://repo.spring.io/milestone was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-milestones has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.2 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have made a new eclipse workspace and tried to rebuild the project numerous times.I have also intialized the project with various versions of spring boot using the initializer.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aptechnolo.moneytree</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneytree</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>moneytree</name>
    <description>Money Tree</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I want to build the project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Resolving this involves two parts:

1. Fix the SSL key verification issue.

   ```
   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   ```

   This means that the certificate presented by https://repo.spring.io/milestone is not trusted by the JDK under which Maven is running. This is tricky to troubleshoot remotely. Is your local JAVA_HOME environment variable pointed at the latest patched version of the JDK? If not, grab the latest patched version and update the environment variable accordingly.
2. Remove the locally cached evidence of the past failure so that Maven will try again.

   ```
   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.2 from https://repo.spring.io/milestone was cached in the local repository
   ```

   This *might* not be necessary, depending on what the update interval of spring-milestones is and whether that amount of time has elapsed since Maven first cached it in your local repo. To clear the cached entry, navigate to `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/` and delete the directory named `2.22.2`. Then try your Maven build again. If you get the SSL error again, we need to work harder on step 1.

Comment: Downloaded the latest JDK version for java 8. Changed preferences. and performed the second step.Still Not Working

Comment: This error is now showing.    An error has occurred.   See the error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException.     This Comes When I Run The Code

```Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:
    Property: driverclassname
    Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration```

Comment: That's completely unrelated to your first question. Your application is building and starting; but failing to initialize completely. Sounds like you're missing a Maven dependency for the MySQL JDBC driver.